# (DynamoDB Collection) Is sortKey required for Collection query?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm making some lambdas to get data from a dynamoDB table.

The DynamoDB table has

- composite primary key

  - 'setId' as partition key (range key) (I used this word 'set' as a noun like 'group' here)
  - 'id' as sort key (hash key)
- 'type' as GSI
- and other attributes ('name' and etc)

[image]

If I understood correctly,

I can use the setId to query because DynamoDb make collections by partition key.

So I tried with this parameters.

```
const params = {
        TableName: MY_TABLE_NAME,
        KeyConditionExpression: `#setId = :setId AND #type = :type `,
        ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#setId": "setId", "#type": "type" },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":setId": { S: "set_1" },
            ":type": { S: "type A" },
        },
    }
```

But it returns error

```
ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: id
```

**Q.**

- Is sort key required to get collection?
- or Did I drop somethings in the parameters?
- or Do I need to set additional something on the table?

Thanks in advance!

FYI) I tried with GSI also and below worked as I expected..

```
const params = {
        TableName: MY_TABLE_NAME,
        IndexName: "blahblah",
        KeyConditionExpression: `#type = :type`,
        FilterExpression: `#setId = :setId`,
        ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#setId": "setId", "#type": "type" },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":setId": { S: "set_1" },
            ":type": { S: "type A" },
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‎You showed us the request *parameters*, but not which request you were doing. DynamoDB has two different read requests relevant to your situation - `GetItem` and `Query`:

- The first, `GetItem`, can only get a **single item**, and a single item is specified by its full primary key (in your case, setId and id). You cannot use `GetItem` and only specify part of the primary key. If you did that, you'd see an error similar to what you saw.
- The second type of request, `Query`, is probably the one you wanted to use. It can get you all the items that have the same partition key (setId), sorted by the sort key (id) - and you don't need to specify a specific sort key in the query. Please read the documentation how to use `Query`, and note the results are paged (in theory a query might return millions of items, and cannot do this in a single page).

Another problem in your request (maybe that's the problem you saw?) is that you tried to to use `#type = :type` in `KeyConditionExpression`. You can't - the key condition is, as its name says, is just for the primary key - and type isn't (unless you're querying the GSI). You should put this condition in the `FilterExpression`, not `KeyConditionExpression`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nadav!! You're right. I moved the `#type=:type` to the FilterExpression and now it's working fine I miss understood the KeyExpression just mean the key and value pair's key. (+ I'm using Query)